# I am having trouble getting values from mongo db through mongoose in the nextjs app

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, next.js13

The issue is that every time it runs it tries to create collection! however i just wants to fetch tasks.

In Task Model File:

```
export class TaskModel extends Mixin(AuditableModel, Mongoose.Schema) {
    constructor(
        public taskId?: number,
        public title?: string,
        public description?: string,
        public isActive?: boolean,
        public creator?: UserModel
    ) {
        super();
    }
}
```

In Task Schema Class

```
export const TaskSchema = mongoose.model('task', new TaskModel())
```

In Task Service File

```
public async GetAll() {
        await mongoose.connect(dbUrl).then(()=>{console.log("Connected")}).catch(()=>{console.log("Not Connected")});
        var response = new Envelop(true, 1000001, TaskSchema.find());
        console.log('Get All!');
        return response;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

please follow this link for better approach https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-find

Note: please dont try `re-open` connection in every `execution` of query. `initiate` the connection when the app initiated.

the code should be look like:

```
public async GetAll() {
    //remove this, except it only for test purpose.
    await mongoose.connect(dbUrl).then(()=>{console.log("Connected")}).catch(()=>{console.log("Not Connected")});

    var response =  await TaskSchema.find()
    console.log('Get All!');
    return response;
}
```